# having chrome extensions pulling data from ruby db

Tags: ruby, google-chrome-extension

I would like to build a chrome extension (CE) that pulls data from a ruby db for a specific user.  So, in a basic example, if an user submits their favorite color as 'red' and sport as 'tennis' into the db from the core website, when they click the CE, 'red' and 'tennis' will show up no matter where they are on the internet.

Any guidance on how to build something like this?  Seems quite simple but am not sure how the CE files fit in with the ruby folder framework.

Also, is it possible to write to a ruby database from a popped out CE? i.e. - submitting 'red' and 'tennis' from the CE to the ruby database to go along with the previous example.  Any guidance?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question so it sounds like you will need to learn a lot. Which can be a good thing :)

Here are the general steps you need:

1. Look into building an API for your ruby application. This will allow you to get data from your database. For example, you can
   make an app where you go to `http://yoursite.com/api/favorites` and that will return a list of all favorites as JSON. Then in your Chrome Extension you can parse the JSON and display the results to the user. You will probably want to do this using an ajax call (see jquery.ajax for an easy way to use ajax).
2. Assuming you want user accounts, your user will need to be logged in. Then you can use your user's cookies to verify that they are logged in and show them custom info. i.e. going to `http://yoursite.com/api/favorites` will just show the favorites for that user, not for everyone.
3. Finally, submitting things to the database...you can have another route where users can send stuff. For example, if you go to `http://yoursite.com/api/favorites/add?color=red` then it will add the color red to that user's favorites. You will need to write all the logic for adding stuff to the database...again, it might help you to go through a rails tutorial and then look at building an API.

Related to #3, look into RESTful APIs. A good convention is that if you issue a `GET` request, you're asking for data, but if you issue a `POST` request, you are adding data (in your case, creating a new favorite).

Finally, for terminology: it's not a "ruby" database, it's just a database. You can access a database using almost any language, and it sounds like you are accessing it using ruby right now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to store data for one machine browsing anywhere online, chrome has a [storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) that would work great.

If you do need a ruby server, I would recommend looking at [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).